# "Function" is not an exported object from "Package"

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I am attempting to develop a package and am having trouble exporting functions from the package.

My issue is that despite the fact that the functions are clearly visible in my packages NAMESPACE function, and after having updated and tested the packaged with document() and test(), when I download the package and attempt to run the function in another session I get the following error error

```
Error: 'get_monthly_listeners' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spotifystreams'
```

On the session with the package in development I had no problem running the following function from the package after using load_all()

```
#' Get Monthly Listeners
#' @export get_monthly_listeners
#' @param artist_code unique 22 alpha-numeric code to identify spotify artists
#' @return An integer represetning total monthly streams of an artists
#' @importFrom rvest read_html html_elements html_text
#' @importFrom dplyr %>%




get_monthly_listeners <- function(artist_code){

  #Spotify link to artists page
  artist_url <- paste0("https://open.spotify.com/artist/", artist_code)

  #Load html data from spotify page in enviroment
  web <- rvest::read_html(artist_url)

  #select all text within div content
  div_content <- web %>% rvest::html_elements("div") %>% rvest::html_text()

  #10th item in the vector contains stream info
  monthly_streams <- div_content[10]

  #seperate text from "monthly listerers"
  monthly_streams <- strsplit(monthly_streams, split = " ")
  #subset list, and then vector to get first element
  monthly_streams <- monthly_streams[[1]][1]
  #remove the comma so we can convert to numeric
  monthly_streams <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", monthly_streams))

  return(monthly_streams)
}


get_monthly_listeners('13y7CgLHjMVRMDqxdx0Xdo')
```

But after downloading the package and attempting to run the same function, I get the error that no functions from within the package are exported.

```
devtools::install_github("liamhaller/spotifystreams", force = TRUE)
library(spotifystreams)

spotifystreams::get_monthly_listeners('13y7CgLHjMVRMDqxdx0Xdo')
```

This is the **namespace in question**: https://github.com/liamhaller/spotifystreams/blob/main/NAMESPACE

And **associated function** from the package: https://github.com/liamhaller/spotifystreams/blob/main/R/get_monthly_listeners.R

Edit: After giving it some time it appears as if the issue might be with devtools::install_github() not updating the version that is hosted on github immediately. The version of the code that is currently being loaded into the install_github() package appears not to have incorporated the most up-to-date changes and is an hour old. I suspect there might be some delay with the version that install_github() downloads

Comment: What output do you get when you run `help( , "spotifystreams")`?  That usually produces a list of functions that are being exported by the package.

Comment: The functions in the package all appear, and when I click on them I even see the usage and descriptions. But still when I try to call them I get the error could not find function "get_monthly_listeners"

Comment: I'm by no means the R package expert, but I was just able to install your package and run the `spotifystreams::get_monthly_listeners('13y7CgLHjMVRMDqxdx0Xdo')` without issue.  Output was `[1] 15453082`.  I had to modify the code associated with installing from github to add the argument `ref = "main"`.  The default argument was the old default branch name `master`.

Comment: Thank you for the support I really appreciate it. On your machine if you look at the source for the function update_streams in the third paragraph down, does the map function read map or purrr::map

Comment: the most up to date version reads purrr::map, but the version I am able to download does not have that change. I suspect there might be some sort of delay with the changes I am making and uploading to github

Comment: `update <- purrr::map(list, list_get_monthly_listerns)`

Comment: There shouldn't really be a delay.  Is it possible that you have a development version already installed, and when you run `install_github()` it fails, so you're left with what you already had (the version from an hour ago, or whatever)?

Comment: Thank you again for the help!! I'm not sure exactly why after sometime it is suddenly working on my machine, but the issue with map/purrr was a problem with my environment

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the function name after "@export". Try the below:

```
#' Get Monthly Listeners
#' @param artist_code unique 22 alpha-numeric code to identify spotify artists
#' @return An integer represetning total monthly streams of an artists
#' @importFrom rvest read_html html_elements html_text
#' @importFrom dplyr %>%
#' @export
get_monthly_listeners <- function(artist_code){

  #Spotify link to artists page
  artist_url <- paste0("https://open.spotify.com/artist/", artist_code)

  #Load html data from spotify page in enviroment
  web <- rvest::read_html(artist_url)

  #select all text within div content
  div_content <- web %>% rvest::html_elements("div") %>% rvest::html_text()

  #10th item in the vector contains stream info
  monthly_streams <- div_content[10]

  #seperate text from "monthly listerers"
  monthly_streams <- strsplit(monthly_streams, split = " ")
  #subset list, and then vector to get first element
  monthly_streams <- monthly_streams[[1]][1]
  #remove the comma so we can convert to numeric
  monthly_streams <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", monthly_streams))

  return(monthly_streams)
}


get_monthly_listeners('13y7CgLHjMVRMDqxdx0Xdo')
```

Comment: This is actually what I originally had, but tried changing it to see if it made a difference.